# How to position the image (called 'self' in the code) in the blue circled spot? I am using Material UI and React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import { Box, Button, Container, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import DownloadButton from "../components/Buttons/DownloadButton";
import GitHubIcon from "@mui/icons-material/GitHub";
import LinkedInIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LinkedIn";
import MainBG from "../assets/MainBG.jpg"
import self from "../assets/self.jpg"




const CustomButton = ({ children }) => (
  <Button
    variant="outlined"
    sx={{
      borderRadius: 4,
      color: "text.primary",
      borderColor: "text.primary",
      height: 45,
      px: 2,
      justifyContent: "flex-start",
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </Button>
);

const Section1 = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Box sx={{position: "fixed", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, zIndex: -10}}>
        <img src={MainBG} alt="Main Background" style={{width: "100%", objectFit: "cover"}} />
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <img src={self} alt="Self Image" style={{position: "absolute", borderRadius: "50%", height: 200, width: 200, objectFit: "cover", right: 0, pb: 5}} /> //this is the image
      </Box>
      <Container sx={{ height: "80vh" }}>
        <Stack sx={{ height: "inherit" }} justifyContent="center">
          <Typography variant="h1" sx={{ letterSpacing: "0.02em", mb: 1 }}>
            Demo
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h3" sx={{ letterSpacing: "0.02em", mb: 4 }}>
            Welcome to my portfolio website.
          </Typography>
          <Stack
            direction={{ xs: "column", md: "row" }}
            alignItems="center"
            spacing={4}
          >
            <DownloadButton sx={{ height: 45, px: 3 }} />
            <CustomButton>
              <GitHubIcon sx={{ fontSize: 32, ml: -1 }} />
              <Stack sx={{ textAlign: "left", ml: 1 }}>
                <Typography variant="caption" sx={{ lineHeight: 1 }}>
                  Explore my work
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h6">on Github</Typography>
              </Stack>
            </CustomButton>
            <CustomButton>
              <LinkedInIcon sx={{ fontSize: 32, ml: -1 }} />
              <Stack sx={{ textAlign: "left", ml: 1 }}>
                <Typography variant="caption" sx={{ lineHeight: 1 }}>
                  Connect professionally
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h6">on Linkedin</Typography>
              </Stack>
            </CustomButton>
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Section1;
```

I am trying like a left side there's the info and right side will be the picture... A standard portfolio home page layout... I tried using css positions or just normal margin stuff, some flexbox things but they don't really give the layout I'm trying to do and feels very hardcoded.. Surely there's an efficient way to design that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/arlQb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you trying to achieve [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrkj5.jpg), I used to Grid instead of Stack as it bit easy to manage the layout on responsive screens.

```
return (
<Box>
  <Box sx={{ position: "fixed", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, zIndex: -10 }}>
    <img
      src={MainBG}
      alt="Main Background"
      style={{ width: "100%", objectFit: "cover" }}
    />
  </Box>
  <Container sx={{ height: "80vh" }}>
    <Grid sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Grid item lg={6}>
        <Typography variant="h1" sx={{ letterSpacing: "0.02em", mb: 1 }}>
          Demo
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h3" sx={{ letterSpacing: "0.02em", mb: 4 }}>
          Welcome to my portfolio website.
        </Typography>
        <Stack
          direction={{ xs: "column", md: "row" }}
          alignItems="center"
          spacing={4}
        >
          <DownloadButton sx={{ height: 45, px: 3 }} />
          <CustomButton>
            <GitHubIcon sx={{ fontSize: 32, ml: -1 }} />
            <Stack sx={{ textAlign: "left", ml: 1 }}>
              <Typography variant="caption" sx={{ lineHeight: 1 }}>
                Explore my work
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="h6">on Github</Typography>
            </Stack>
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton>
            <LinkedInIcon sx={{ fontSize: 32, ml: -1 }} />
            <Stack sx={{ textAlign: "left", ml: 1 }}>
              <Typography variant="caption" sx={{ lineHeight: 1 }}>
                Connect professionally
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="h6">on Linkedin</Typography>
            </Stack>
          </CustomButton>
        </Stack>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item lg={6}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            height: "100%",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <img
            src={self}
            alt="Self Image"
            style={{
              // position: "absolute",
              borderRadius: "50%",
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              objectFit: "cover",
              // right: 0,
              pb: 5,
            }}
          />
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Container>
</Box>
```

);